# delete on pointer (*&) to base class with virtual destructor c++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, polymorphism

So, I have a game-server running on a very old system (2006-2007) that creates a player object when a players logs in, a monster object when a monster is created and a npc object when npcs appear. All these classes derive from the creature class and all of them have virtual destructors. So, when I create these objects I add them to a creature vector (not an actual STL vector but a custom made template) with operator() overloaded. I wrote this dummy code to show easily.

```
vector<Creature *> CreatureList(100);

template <typename T>
struct vector {
    vector(int InitialSize);
    int InitialSize;
    T& operator()(int i);
    T* Entry; // At constructor, this is 'Entry = new T[InitialSize];' and is deleted at destructor.
};

struct Creature {
    Creature();
    virtual ~Creature();
    bool IsOnMap;
    char Name[30];
};

struct Player : Creature {
    Player();
    virtual ~Player();
    int PlayerState;
    int PlayerID;
};

struct Monster : Creature {
    Monster();
    virtual ~Monster();
    int SpawnPosX, SpawnPosY;
    int Health;
};

struct NPC : Creature {
    NPC();
    virtual ~NPC();
    Object TradeChest;
    int SpawnPosX, SpawnPosY;
};

int OnPlayerLogin() {
    Player *pl = new Player;
    CreatureList(NextCreatureID++) = pl;
    return PlayerID;
}

void OnMonsterSpawn() {
    Monster *mn = new Monster;
    CreatureList(NextCreatureID++) = mn;
}

void OnNPCSpawn() {
    NPC *npc = new NPC;
    CreatureList(NextCreatureID++) = npc;
}

void ProcessAllCreatures() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NextCreatureID; i++) {
        Creature* cr = CrList(i); // this doesn't return Creature* but actually Creature*&
        if (!cr)
            continue;

        if (!cr->IsOnMap)
            delete cr; // This spits a SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault).
    }
}
```

This dummy code assumes that all initialization is done at constructors. `NextCreatureID` is just an auto-increment var that works as an index. The custom vector class is just an auto-resizable array and operator() will always return the reference to the actual object (this can't change due to internal code convention).

Problem is that it sends a SIGSEGV to the process and if I try `delete &cr` I get SIGABRT because of invalid pointer. So, is there any way to fix this without having to change the vector class? (which is impossible for me to do because of collab. work as I said).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!cr)
    continue;
```

will not work like you intend it to. `delete`ing a pointer doesn't reset it to `nullptr`. In your first call to ProcessAllCreatures() everything may work fine, when you call it a second time you will delete already deleted pointers, because you will never `continue`when looking at a already deleted pointer.

Comment: Such a dumb mistake I made. I will have to re-read that old pointer book. I've marked this as the answer.